# removing a repetitive sequence

Tags: ruby

Im new to Ruby and I like some pointers please.  I have a file that contains many of the following:

UPDATE:

```
+ 

?@??>=???>?>??>?>=9>>==?2>===<=>=== @IL9_2657:1:1:1:1217/1 

TTTTCCGTGCTTTTTTTTTCGGTTCGATCCCCTCTTT

 +
```

I want a script that will say for each block that contains + to +, remove the block if the sequence has a

```
TTTTTTTTT.
```

Thanks in advance.

Mark

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
s = 'preceding_string+ ?@??>=???>?>??>?>=9>>==?2>===<=>=== @IL9_2657:1:1:1:1217/1 TTTTCCGTGCTTTTTTTTTCGGTTCGATCCCCTCTTT +following_string'

s.gsub!(/\+[^+]*TTTTTTTTT[^+]*\+/, '')
p s

# => "preceding_stringfollowing_string"
```

Answer (score 1):

First split your data into an array. [`scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001181) can do this with a simple regular expression. You can then remove the unwanted items with [`reject!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000259). For example:

```
data = "+x+ +y+ +TTTTTTTTT+ +z+"

blocks = data.scan(/\+[^+]+\+/)
blocks.reject! { |b| b.include? "TTTTTTTTT" }

p blocks
# => ["+x+", "+y+", "+z+"]
```

Comment: Thanks but this is assuming they are all in one line.  I've updated above

Answer (score 1):

```
ruby -0777 -ne 'puts $_.split(/\+/).reject{|x| x[/TTTTTTT/] }.join("+")' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Could the sequence have too many adenines? If so, use bioruby to get the reverse complement of the sequence.