# stdin doesnt work ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following script:

```
$stdin.each_line do |data|    
  blocks = data.scan(/\+[^+]+\+/)
  blocks.reject! { |b| b.include? "AAAAAAAAA" }    
  p blocks    
end
```

This script will remove that string of A's in a stdin file.  I have two questions:

1. The stdin doesnt seem to work, it outputs `[]`.
2. How can I modify the script to say that *reject a stretch of single letters that have length 20 or above*, so if there is a stretch of 20 or more A's, remove the block.

Comment: How are you sending the input? Could you also add a test input/output that you want?

Comment: What do you mean by "It doesn't work"? If I execute your script and enter +AAAAA++BBBBB++AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA+ I get
["+AAAAA+", "+BBBBB+"] just as expected.

Comment: I think your regular expression is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I agree with @Mike - you probably have the wrong regex. What exactly are you trying to split / reject? Please provide an example.

Comment: @Frank Schmitt I think he wants to detect if the line has 20 of the same characters in a row, and if it does, reject that line. I'm not a regex expert so I won't try to give a solution but, I'm pretty sure that's what he's looking for.

Comment: Yes Mike is right, thats exacly what I am looking for

Comment: Not sure, but could possibly be related to / same as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646907/removing-a-repetitive-sequence/5646950#5646950 question. Molecular biology study or something? `A` stands for adenine?

Comment: Mark, Could you please add some sample input and the desired output?

Comment: @sawa: I bet it is. A lot of As (this question) is the reverse complement of a lot of Ts (the previous question).

Comment: @Andrew I see. I didn't realize that. Now, it's more likely.

Answer (score 0):

To reject all blocks with 20 or more identical uppercase characters:

```
$stdin.each_line do |data|
  blocks = data.scan(/\+[^+]+\+/)
  ('A'..'Z').each do |ch|
    r = Regexp.new("[" + ch + "]{20,}")
    blocks.reject! { |b| r =~ b }
  end
  p blocks
end
```

This builds 26 regexes (one for each uppercase character) and matches blocks against them.
Of course, it would be much more efficient to build them just once and store them in an array or similar instead of rebuilding them for each line in the input.

A more compact solution:

```
  r = /([a-z])\1{19,}/
  $stdin.each_line do |data|
      blocks = data.scan(/\+[^+]+\+/)
      blocks.reject! { |b| r =~ b }
      p blocks
  end
```

This one uses a single regular expression to match a single character, and 19 or more occurences of the same character directly afterwards (using a back reference).

Comment: Did you test it? If you run this script and enter +AAAAA++BBBBB++AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA+ in one line, you get ["+AAAAA+", "+BBBBB+"] just as expected. If this is not what you expect, please explain what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have a file that contains many + /n to /n + when I run the script and when i enter the data file number it outputs only [].  any idea why? thanks

Comment: @Mark please post a COMPLETE example of a session, including the data you enter on STDIN, and explain where your script behaves differently from what you expect!

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression for your reject! statement is:

```
/([A-Z])\1{19}/
```

This matches any capital letter followed by 19 more of the exact same letter.